# How can I use data from an Access form in a PickerView in Xcode 8/Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm looking to try to utilize data from different classes in school inside of a pickerview, so that people could effectively choose their preferred schedule inside the app, and save it to a table view. I can't find any useful information concerning importing database information to a picker view, or on how to save their choice to a User Editable table view...thoughts?

Comment: StackOverflow is a community that can help you with your programming, but we're not here to write code for you.  Please edit your question to provide more details on how you've tried to solve this problem.  The very first search result I get for "swift database picker" provides exactly what you're asking for, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want insert the data to pickerview try this.

```
    var gender = ["Male", "Female"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return gender.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let titleRow = gender[row]
    return titleRow
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.textBox.text = self.gender[row]
    self.pickerViewGender.isHidden = true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField){
    if textField == self.textBox{
        self.pickerViewGender.isHidden = false
        //if you want to hidden the keyboard
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

but dont forget to connect your view to the ViewController.swift